# Why do we use the super() method in a child class in python

Tags: python, function, class, methods, super

So in python to call a parent classes function in a child class we use the `super()` method but why do we use the `super()` when we can just call the Parent class function suppose i have a `Class Employee:`  and i have another class which inherites from the Employee class `class Programmer(Employee):` to call any function of Employee class in Programmer class i can just use `Employee.functionName()` and that does the job.
Here is some code:

```
class Person:
    country = "India"

    def takeBreath(self):
        print("I am breathing...")

class Employee(Person):
    company = "Honda"

    def getSalary(self):
        print(f"Salary is {self.salary}")
    
    def takeBreath(self):
        print("I am an Employee so I am luckily breathing...")

class Programmer(Employee):
    company = "Fiverr"

    def getSalary(self):
        print(f"No salary to programmer's.")
    
    def takeBreath(self):
        Employee().takeBreath()
        print("I am a Programmer so i am breathing++..")

p = Person()
p.takeBreath()

e = Employee()
e.takeBreath()

pr = Programmer()
pr.takeBreath()
```

As you can see i wanted to call the Employee functions `takeBreath()` method in the `Programmer()` class so i just wrote `Employee.takeBreath()` which also does the job so can anyone explain me why we  need the `super()` method in python?

#### :)

Comment: In `Programmer.takeBreath`, you created a new `Employee` instance, so its output are from that instance, not that class.  Calling `super()` will return a super of the current instance.

Comment: Means? Can you explain?

Comment: Your `Programmer.takeBreath` is making a *new* employee and telling *that guy* to take a breath.

Comment: Wait so if i have a `__init__` function everytime it will call that whenever i use Employee.takeBreath while super() will only call it once and then you can call the other functions continuosly

Comment: In your code you have `Employee().takeBreath()` which creates an `Employee` instance and then calls its `takeBreath` method. This is unrelated to `super()`.

Comment: Ok thanks i get it

Comment: "One benefit of indirection is that we don’t have to specify the delegate class by name. If you edit the source code to switch the base class to some other mapping, the super() reference will automatically follow" https://rhettinger.wordpress.com/2011/05/26/super-considered-super/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You already got a few answers as to why your code doesn't work (you're creating a new `Employee` rather than calling `Employee`'s method with your own `self`) and why delegation via `super` is convenient (don't have to update all the code if you update the parent class).

An other reason is that Python supports *multiple inheritance*, and explicit delegation simply can't work with a *diamond inheritance* pattern.

A diamond pattern is something like that:

```
    A
   / \
  /   \
 B     C
  \   /
   \ /
    D
```

```py
class A:
    def foo(self):
        ...
class B(A):
    def foo(self):
        ...
class C(A):
    def foo(self):
        ...
class D(C, B):
    def foo(self):
        ...
```

"D" extends both "B" and "C", and also overrides "foo" to add its own stuff. "D" can't just call "B::foo" and "C::foo": if it does that, then *both* will in turn call "A::foo", which will be invoked twice, to potential ill effects if it has dangerous side-effects.

If you use `super()`, then Python manages the chain using the *method resolution order* (specifically [C3](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C3_linearization)): when classes are created, it generates a *linear* sequence of all parent classes, and when calling `super()` it simply walks that sequence from where it is to find the "parent" method, even between completely unrelated classes.

Here the MRO would be D -> C -> B -> A, so when `D` calls `super().foo()`, Python will invoke `C::foo`, whose super will call `B::foo` *despite C and B having no knowledge of one another.

Comment: So if i have super and And inside the c and d classes `foo` method i write the `super().foo()` the D `super.foo()` will go to C `super().foo` and C `super.foo()` will go to B `super().foo()` while as if i call the class name and the function it will go to the D class foo function which will go to the C class foo function which will go to the  A class foo function so that mans the super method manages **`Multiple inheritence` `Mutilevel inheritance` safer and better right?**

Comment: So if i have two classes and suppose the classes functions are very badly organized and i create another class which inherites from `class1disorganized,  class2sisorganzied` and both classes have a lot of functions in it and i know that there i one function named `name_of_function()` and that this function is present in either one of the classes and if i want to use that function in a newclass i have just create a newclass inheriting from thos two classes and call the super mwthod for that function while as if there was no super method function i had to specify the class name and it would be

Comment: difficult for many disorgazied classes and functions without the super() method right?

Answer (score 2):

With `super()` you don't need to define `takeBreath()` in each class inherited from the `Person()` class.

Answer (score 1):

`super()` is a far more general method. Suppose you decide to change your superclass. Maybe you name it `Tom` instead of `Employee`. Now you have to go about and change every mention of your `Employee` call.

You can think of `super()` as a "proxy" to get the superclass regardless of what it is. It enables you to write more flexible code.

Though, what you are doing is different. You are creating a new instance of Employee each time, and then calling the method on it. If you change your `takeBreath` method to not take a `self` parameter, you will be able to do something like `Employee.takeBreath()`, or better, `super().takeBreath()`.